# Rspec reloads removes the value that updated earlier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

why reload removes the values that has been updated on before(:each)

is there any other approach for doing such things

thanks in advance
i have written my rspec as below

```
let!(:book){FactoryGirl.create(:book)
let!(:book2){FactoryGirl.create(:book)

before(:each) do
  book.update_column(name:"my new book")
  book2.update_column(name:"my second book")
end

it "does updation of name" do
  data = book.rename_book
  expect(book.reload.name).to eq("some new name")
  expect(book2.reload.name).to not_eq("some new name") // here it removes the book name and make it as nil, how to prevent this
end

//the book2.reload is removes the book name and update it as nil, as how to fix it as it should display the second book name, instead it displays nil for that book.
```

Comment: What are you trying to test here?

Comment: @Jon as rename book method will gave a default name for those books, so that if the method calls then it will rename the book name, but for the book2 it wont call so it should not be changed to the default name

Comment: @spickermann as book2.reload.name contains nil, after using the reload on it, but i need it to be "my second book" as i have updated it on before(:each)

Comment: `update_column` doesn't expect a hash but two values, the attribute, and the value. Try `book2.update_column(:name, "my second book")` instead.

Comment: @spickermann yeah, but again the reload gaves the nil for the second book

Comment: Are you sure that the update in the before block actually was successfully persisted to the database? How did you check that? Because if the record was changed but the save wasn't successful then it absolutely makes sense that the `reload` resets the record to the previous version form the database.

Comment: what is the source of `rename_book` method?

Comment: It is really hard to help you here - this might be an actual bug in your code and not a problem with reload. Have you confirmed that the attribute is set correctly after `update_attribute`? One note - `reload` does not update anything as `nil` - it simply reads the record from the database again, so if after `relaod` the value is nil it means it is nil in the database